# Correct Assignment for Pointers

Tags: pointers

I am shifting from Python to C so bit rusty on the semantics as well as coding habit. In Python everything is treated as an object and objects are passed to functions. This is not the case in C so I want to increment an integer using pointers. What is the correct assignment to do so. I want to do it the following way but have the assignments wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i = 24;
int increment(*i){
*i++;
return i;
}
int main() {
increment(&i);
printf("i = %d,  i);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i = 24;
// changed from i to j in order to avoid confusion.
// note you could declare the return type as void instead
int increment(int *j){
    (*j)++;
    return *j;
}
int main() {
    increment(&i);
    printf("i = %d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Your main error was the missing `int` in the function's argument (also a missing `"` in the printf).

Also I would prefer using parentheses in expressions as `*j++` and specify exactly the precedence like I did in `(*j)++`, because I want to increment the content of the variable in the 'j' location **not** to increment the pointer - meaning to point it on the next memory cell - and then use its content.

Comment: Thanks, Coming from python I am in a process of coping with c syntax so its a great help.

Comment: I just have one question, unlike python, why is main function taking in the variable `i`, if I have not passed it into the function? So it looks like the functions in C isnt fully encapsulated. Right? In python I will have to give variable `i`, in the arguments of the function, but here without passing the arguments it is accessing the variable. Should function's scope be limited to its arguments?

Comment: @gfdsal that's because you declared the i variable outside any function i.e. in the global scope. Thus i is a global variable and can be accessed from any function without declaring. (unless you declare another i variable inside a function which will override the global i variable for that function)